# Informatica bad file row indicator

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I was reading about bad file in Informatica and it was very clear concept. However, didn't understand following row indicators :-

```
"Rolled-back insert" = Writer
"Rolled-back update" = Writer
"Rolled-back delete" = Writer
"Committed insert" = Writer
"Committed update" = Writer
"Committed delete" = Writer
```

I'm trying to understand when above scenario will happen? I mean when and how "Rolled-back insert" and other indicators will happen?

Source 
https://dwbi.org/etl/informatica/143-informatica-reject-or-bad-files

Comment: It would be great if you could share the source, so the context would be easier to get.

Comment: @Maciejg I have added source in the question. If you google with "bad files informatica", most of the links shows this particular table.

Answer (score 0):

Very good and straight forward question. 
Basically data base table may have some constraints or indexes associated for one or more columns. For example, if the source data is null and it is a not null column in a target table in this case following operation is occurred,

Rolled-back insert 
Rolled-back update 
Rolled-back delete

Like wise for primary key column insertion of duplicate values. These or some reasons.

After successful data loading commit process occurs based on the operation you perform in the mapping such as insert, update or delete.

Committed insert 
Committed update 
Committed delete

Even though commit operation is triggered, data will not be reflected in the target for the above mentioned reasons.

Hope you got what you want. If not kindly raise your queries.

Comment: Thanks Jim for the answer. Few doubts :-
1) How Insert, "Rolled-back insert", "Committed insert"" are diffferent. 
2) Its mentioned that Rolled-back insert, Committed insert are "Rejected by" writer. Writer here means Informatica, correct? So how come Informatica writer can reject the rows if there are contraints defined at target table.